# Domain Driven Design: Can Infrastructure or Repositories use Domain objects?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Considering Domain Driven Design, can Infrastructure or System use Domain's objects (Values, Entities, etc.), or should it be applied Dependency Inversion, so that Infrastructure will only depend on Interfaces defined by itself?

What about the Repository? Does it applies de same?

Is it a violation to a Infrastructure, Repository or a System code depends on the Domain?

(A) Example code where Infrastructure depends on the Domain:

```
namespace Infrastrcuture {
    public class Sender {
        public void Send (Domain.DataValue data) { ... }
    }
}
```

(B) Example code where Infrastructure will not depend on the Domain:

```
namespace Infrastrcuture {
    public interface ISendableData {
        ...
    }
    public class Sender {
        public void Send (ISendableData data) { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I'd say it's OK if your infrastructure depends on your domain. The other way around is not such a good idea.

Think about it this way: what is more likely to be replaced at some point? Infrastructure or domain?

Infrastructure will change over time (different providers, different servers, ...) Your domain on the other hand will always be there

Comment: If you design considering that Infrastructure can depend (in the means of the `using` keyword) on the Domain, how can you avoid cyclic dependency? Since Domain will use Infrastructure's services that depends on the Domain.

Comment: Well, the domain should depend on interfaces to the infrastructure, not infrastructure itself. As in, the domain defines the interface it needs and then you provide an implementation for that interface

Comment: So Domain will declare Interfaces of services it needs, then Infrastructure, Repositories and etc. will implement it ? Now it makes sense to me. 
What is your approach to selecting the implementation of such an Interface? Dependency Injection? Passing the implementation to the constructor? Global configuration context?

Comment: Dependency Injection. [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) explains this approach in more details.

Comment: @FelipeLavratti I have hard time understanding what do you mean by using DI or passing implementation to the constructor. I think you might be thinking of something *Not So Nice* so it would be good if you share some code. Usually, your domain would need to know nothing about the infrastructure in any sense, not even by own interfaces and constructor injection. For example, repositories know how to persist your entities but entities know nothing about repositories and persistence.